# Change bootstrap nav style to remove the padding right below a nav?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get rid of a padding styled to a bootstrap `nav`.

I have the following relevant markup for my `nav`:

```
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
```

And I've tried:

```
.navbar-default {
  padding-bottom: -20px;
  padding-top: -10px;
}
```

And also:

```
#menu {
  padding-bottom: -20px;
}
```

This is how its being displayed:

[image]

So I want the blue `div` displayed right below the `nav` with any padding.

How can I get it?

This is my whole html for `nav` and `div` below:

```
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">Inicio</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="taylor.html">Aproximación de Taylor</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Aproximación de raíces<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Bisección</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Newton Raphson</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Secante</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Iteración de Punto Fijo</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>


        <div id="argumentos" class="form-actions">
        <input list="funciones" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Función" id="fx">
        <datalist id="funciones">
            <option value="x**3+4*x**2-10">
            <option value="x**3-x-1">
            <option value="e**(x)+2**(-x)+2*cos(x)-6">
            <option value="e**(x)-x**2+3*x-2">
            <option value="(4*x-7)/(x-2)**2">
        </datalist>
        <input type="text" placeholder="a" id="a" style="width: 50px;">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="b" id="b" style="width: 50px;">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="tolerancia "id="tolerancia" style="width: 75px;">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Iteraciones máximas" id="iteracionesMaximas" style="width: 140px;">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Visión en a" id="a-vision" style="width: 75px;">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Visión en b" id="b-vision" style="width: 75px;">
        <button id="ok" class="btn btn-success">Graficar</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: I didn't see any padding using your code. can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: you cant apply negative padding.

Comment: what do you mean by " I want the blue div displayed right below the nav"? and i cant see any blue div in this http://jsfiddle.net/9J88Z/

Comment: Come on I got any in line css style but that's why I included an image. There's an empty space between bootstrap nav and the div below

Comment: okay so you dont want that margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of margin not the padding. Simply write in your css:

```
.navbar {margin-bottom:0px;}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9J88Z/1/)

Comment: Stupid question, when is it about margin and when is it about padding?

Comment: Not a stupid question, but pretty much you just have to check both. If it has color than I think padding includes the color, whereas margin doesn't, but that didn't help you here

Comment: @TMP : Please help me to understand the question first then :D :D

Comment: I don't even know Era's opinion about question

Comment: I believe @diegoaguilar wanted to know when to check for padding versus when to check for margin. IE: which would be causing what types of problems

Comment: @diegoaguilar : i hope u got.. padding versus margin. and thanks TMP :) :)

Comment: Aha, I asked what @TMP said

Comment: Weird but it's not working in my project. It did when applied to the fiddle though

Comment: try applying !important `.navbar {margin-bottom:0px !important;}`

Comment: Its because, our CSS declaration was not specific enough to understand by the browser. Read about CSS Specificity http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/

Comment: Sorry I went to sleep, but normally it's good to avoid `!important`, an alternative here would be to just specify more specific css. But @Era's link should help

Answer (score 2):

```
.navbar {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: you cant give padding in negative pixels. X(

Comment: i copy that from the question... XD sorry for that~